# Using mutate, if_else, and rowSums to create a new var based on condition

Tags: r, dplyr, case-when, rowsum, if-case

I have a data frame  which is in long format. I have multiple cities. Each of the cities has information for each month and information also for each code (this code goes from 100 up to 1,000). My dataframe looks like this:

| Code | City | month | Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | A | 10 | 0 |
| 100 | B | 12 | 1 |
| 100 | A | 10 | 2 |
| 100 | B | 12 | 3 |
| 100 | A | 10 | 4 |
| 100 | B | 12 | 5 |
| 200 | A | 10 | 10 |
| 200 | B | 12 | 11 |
| 200 | A | 10 | 12 |
| 200 | B | 12 | 13 |
| 200 | A | 10 | 14 |
| 200 | B | 12 | 15 |

I´m trying to create a new var that adds up the information in the **Data** variable foreach month when the variable **Code** is equal to 100. So for the 10th month I would have a result of 6, and for the 12th month I would have a result of 9:

| Code |
| --- |
| 6 |
| 9 |
| 6 |
| 9 |
| 6 |
| 9 |
| 6 |
| 9 |
| 6 |
| 9 |
| 6 |
| 9 |

For this I´m using **dplyr**:

```
df <- df %>%
group_by(month) %>% 
mutate(newvar =case_when(Code==100 ~ as.integer(rowSums(select_(., "Data"), na.rm = TRUE))))
```

However, I´m getting an error and I haven´t been able to create this new variable correctly. I know that an easier way would be using base R. But I want to use **dplyr**.

Any help is really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `sum` the `Data` value only where `Code = 100` for each `month`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(month) %>%
  mutate(newvar = sum(Data[Code == 100], na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also do

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(month) %>%
   mutate(newvar = sum(case_when(Code == 100 ~ Data), na.rm = TRUE))
```